# How does the Fast Modular Exponentiation Algorithm handle recursive calls?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, number-theory

I have been taught the Fast Modular Exponentiation Algorithm as shown below.

```
FastExponentiation(a, p, n):
  if p = 0 then
    return 1
  if p is even then
    t <- FastExponentiation(a, p/2, n)
    return t^2 mod n
  t <- FastExponentiation(a, (p-1)/2, n)
  return a(t^2 mod n) mod n
```

How do the second and third return statements ever get reached when running this program? There is a recursive call before these two statements so surely the program would just enter a recursive loop?

Comment: If `p` is getting halved each time, it will eventually reach `0` and the "recursive loop" would break.

Comment: But then how would the second and third return statements every be reached? Surely this function would always eventually return 1 and never anything else?

Comment: Have you tried to dry run the algorithm using small input values? That would clarify your questions.

Comment: Not yet but will give it a go with python. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The "deepest" call will always return 1, but then it returns that up only one level, that return doesn't skip over everything all the way up to when the function was first called.

Comment: Yh makes sense now. Appreciate the help!

Comment: As with any other function, it returns to the point where it was invoked and execution resumes from there. If the invocation was a different instance of the recursive function, so be it. It still works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet below can illustrate you how `p` decreases while going deeper into the recursion, until it becomes `1`. On the next recursive call it becomes zero: `(1-1)/2` → `0`.

```js
function fastExp (a, p, n, level = 0, pExpr = '') {
    if (level == 0) {
        console.log(`Fast exponentiation: ${a} ^ ${p} mod ${n}`);
    }
    console.log(`${'  '.repeat(level)}> p = ${pExpr}${p}`);
    let res;
    if (p == 0) {
        res = 1;
    }
    else if ((p & 1) == 0) {
        let t = fastExp(a, p/2, n, level+1, `${p}/2 = `);
        res = (t*t) % n;
    }
    else {
        let t = fastExp(a, (p-1)/2, n, level+1, `(${p}-1)/2 = `);
        res = (a * ((t*t) % n)) % n;
    }
    console.log(`${'  '.repeat(level)}> ${a} ^ ${p} mod ${n} = ${res}`);
    return res;
}

function rand () { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 50; }
fastExp(rand(), rand(), rand());
```